# Не удаётся скопировать файл

Tags: php

```
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="4_1_action.php" METHOD="POST"> 
<INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"> 
<INPUT name="ok" TYPE="submit" value="Передать файл"> 
</FORM> 


<?php  
if(isset($_FILES["file"]))  
{ 
    $catalog = "image";  
    if (is_dir($catalog))  
    {
        $myfile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
        $myfile_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
        if(!copy($myfile, $catalog)) echo "Ошибка при копировании файла ".$myfile_name;
    }
    else mkdir('image');
}
?>
```

При выборе файла и нажатии на кнопку выдаёт ошибку:

> Warning: copy() [function.copy]: The second argument to copy()
>   function cannot be a directory in Z:\home\prakt\www\4_1_action.php on
>   line 9 Ошибка при копировании файла 04.jpg

Подскажите, в чём дело?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Чем copy не подходит ?

Comment: `copy` - Копирует файл source в файл с **именем** dest....... а вы ему директорию суете вторым параметром.....Допиши в конец слеш и имя.

Comment: Ошибку перестало выдавать, но в папке нету скопированного файла.

Comment: Значит неправильно задан путь к директории, может нужно `/images`, а может `mysupersite/cawabunga/images`..... в зависимости от того, какая структура у проекта и как настроена маршрутизация.....ибо ошибка только в этом была......почти...ваш `else` избыточен.... можно написать так `if (!is_dir($catalog))  
 mkdir('image');

$myfile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
$myfile_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
if(!copy($myfile, $catalog.'/'.$myfile_name)) echo "Ошибка при копировании файла ".$myfile_name;`  где после `mkdir('image');` надо нажать `enter`

Comment: Спасибо.Буду исправлять.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрим в документацию: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php

`copy` - Копирует файл `source` в файл с **именем** `dest`.

Вы же пытаетесь отдать вторым параметром директорию.

Вам нужно дописать в конец слеш и имя: `copy($myfile, $catalog.'/'.$myfile_name)`

---

Также замечу, что условие `else` избыточно. Можно в начале проверять на существование директории, и если её нет создавать. Остальные конструкции по копированию файла оставить ниже.

В итоге. если представить, что у вас структура вот такая:

```
- index.php (с формой)
- 4_1_action.php (обработчик)
- images (папка с картинками, в одной директории с 4_1_action.php)
  - photo_1.jpg
  - photo_2.jpg
  ...
...
```

то код обработчика будет таков:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"])) { 
    $catalog = "image";  

    if (!is_dir($catalog)) 
       mkdir('image');

    $myfile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $myfile_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    if (!copy($myfile, $catalog. '/'.$myfile_name)) 
       echo "Ошибка при копировании файла ".$myfile_name      
}
```